# Why is my int() function not working python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, int

```
def game():    

modex = False
while modex == False:
    mode = raw_input("please select a mode: ")
    try:
    ## THE PROBLEM IS HERE!
        int(mode)
        if mode == 1:
            modex = True
            break
        elif mode == 2:
            modex = True
            break
        elif mode == 3:
            modex = True
            break
        else:
            print "invalid #. try again"
            modex == False
            continue

    except:
        print "invalid # try again"
        continue
game()
```

i can't seem to turn mode into an integer, for example:

input: 1
output: invalid # try again

for the game i am making i have 3 modes hence the 3 modes if statement in the try-except statement

could you please help me? I am using python 2.7

Comment: It should be `mode = int(mode)`

Comment: either use `modex` or `break`. That is, use `break`. The `continue` is unnecessary.

Comment: `while True` will do the same thing, modex is redundant, you also don't seem to return anything so I don't see what the function is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asign the `int(mode)` value to something. Best approach: `mode = int(mode)`

You can also try: `mode = int(raw_input:('please select a mode:'))`

Comment: Thanks toni my code is now working!